# C++, Linked Lists for Priority Queues

Tags: c++, linked-list, priority-queue

I'm working on an assignment and the goal is to make a module that will assist in representing a priority queue displaying each 'item' and it's appropriate 'priority value'. I'm not asking anybody to do my "homework" for me as stated in my previous post, I'm simply asking for help understanding where I am going wrong with my `insert` and `insertCell` functions that gives me errors. Any advice/tips would be very helpful in solving my problem.

```
//Beginning of Code
//File: pqueue.cpp


//Module pqueue.cpp provides priority queues that include items and their 
//priority types. It tests for empty queues, can insert priority queues that
//include a new item with a new priority, can remove priority queues and/or
//items with their priorities, and can print each item along with its priority
//to the standard output.
//
//

#include <cstdio>
#include "pqueue.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//An object of type PQCell represents a cell in a linked list.
//
//PQCell has three field.
//
//item- the particular item that is entered
//priority- the priority that an item has
//nextList- a pointer to the next cell in the list
struct PQCell
{ 
    ItemType item;
    PriorityType priority;
    PQCell *nextItem;

    PQCell(ItemType a, PriorityType b, PQCell* nextCell)
    {
        item = a;
        priority = b;
        nextItem = nextCell;
    }   
};

//Function isEmpty returns true if the queue is empty and false if it is not.
bool isEmpty(const PriorityQueue& q)
{
    if(q.cells == NULL)
    {
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}   

//Function insertCell inserts item x with priority p into a linked list 'L'.
void insertCell(PQCell*& L, ItemType x, PriorityType p)
{
    if(L==NULL || L -> priority > p)
    {
        L = new PQCell(x, p, L);
    }

    else
    {
        insertCell(L -> nextItem, x,p);
    }
}

//Function insert inserts item x with priority p into a priority queue 'q'.
void insert(PriorityQueue& q, ItemType x, PriorityType p)
{
    insertCell(q, x, p);
}

//Function printPriorityQueue prints a representation of the priority queue 
//including each value, x, and it's priority type, y, respectively.
void printPriorityQueue(const PriorityQueue& q, ItemPrinter printItem, 
        PriorityPrinter printPriority)
{
    PQCell* pointer = q.cells;
    while(pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("Item = ");
        (printItem)(pointer->item);

        printf("     Priority = ");
        (printPriority)(pointer->priority);

        printf("\n");

        pointer = pointer -> nextItem;
    }
}

//Function remove removes the item with the smallest priority. It also stores
//the item and it's priority into x and p, respectively.
void remove(PriorityQueue& q, ItemType& x, PriorityType& p)
{
    if(q.cells != NULL)
    {
        PQCell *pointer = q.cells;
        q.cells = q.cells -> nextItem;
        x = pointer -> item;
        p = pointer -> priority;
        delete [] pointer;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Q is empty");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

---

```
//File: pqueue.h



typedef const char* ItemType;
typedef double      PriorityType;
struct PQCell;
typedef void (*ItemPrinter)(ItemType);
typedef void (*PriorityPrinter)(PriorityType);



struct PriorityQueue
{
    PQCell* cells;

    PriorityQueue()
    {
        cells = NULL;
    }
};

bool isEmpty(const PriorityQueue& q);

void insert(PriorityQueue& q, ItemType x, PriorityType p);

void printPriorityQueue(const PriorityQueue& q, ItemPrinter printItem, 
        PriorityPrinter printPriority);

void remove(PriorityQueue& q, ItemType& x, PriorityType& p);
```

The main problem I'm having is like I said, the `insert` and `insertCell` functions. I keep receiving the errors:

```
pqueue.cpp: In function void insert(PriorityQueue*&, ItemType, PriorityType):

pqueue.cpp:70:20: error: invalid initialization of reference of type PQCell*& from expression of type PriorityQueue*
  insertCell(q, x, p);

pqueue.cpp:54:6: error: in passing argument 1 of void insertCell(PQCell*&, ItemType, PriorityType)
 void insertCell(PQCell*& L, ItemType x, PriorityType p)
```

Again, any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: A `PriorityQueue&` is not a `PQCell*&`. That clearly explains all error messaging. That call should be passing `q.cells` as the first argument, from what i see.

Comment: Instead of passing a reference to a pointer to `insertCell()`, why don't you just return the pointer to the new `PQCell`?   I find the mix of references and pointers confusing, is there a reason why you don't use pointer-to-pointer?  Don't we teach pointer-to-pointers any more?

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggest and it fixed the errors @WhozCraig, Thanks.

Comment: @Kingsley we were giving specific instructions to use those two function headings how they are, which unfortunately means if I change it to make it easier for me, it will lower the grade received.

Comment: Fair enough - but `Param *&` would never pass a code review at any company I've ever worked at.

Comment: Which is why I contemplate not taking this professor again. @Kingsley

Comment: @Kingsley Are you saying that `Param**` would pass code review? Seems even worse to me.

Comment: @John, as long as it was an appropriate use, sure.  Every `argv` is a `**` !

Comment: @Kingsley I'm curious; what specifically would cause every company you ever worked for to reject a check-in with that construct, and in particular, what are te related reasons *other* than the reviewers pure opinion of style. Don't misunderstand; I prefer passing my in/out pointer parameters by address (pointer to pointer; a holdover from my many years in C before coming home to C++ 25 years ago, as it reserve my option to return success/error state as the result), but I'd love to have a generally-accepted industry guideline to fallback on when telling juniors to just don't do that?

Comment: @WhozCraig - I don't know of any "generally-accepted industry guideline".  When I was a junior, I was told in a code review: "C++ references should be used *only* for operator overloading" (i.e.: returning an object reference to support assignment).  I personally have no issue with using references for a "var parameter" (although pointers are my preference too), but not *mixing* references and pointers.  Maybe I've turned into a coding curmudgeon over the years.  Seems nowdays if you use `**` in C/C++ you obviously hate  kittens too.  Seems so on SO at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem (the one that's causing the `invalid initialization` error) is that you're passing a `PriorityQueue&` into a function that's expecting a `PQCell*&`:

```
//Function insert inserts item x with priority p into a priority queue 'q'.
void insert(PriorityQueue& q, ItemType x, PriorityType p)
{
   // Wrong.
   //insertCell(q, x, p);

   // You probably meant to do this:
   insertCell(q.cells, x, p);
}
```

I also noticed that your `isEmpty` logic seems to be backwards:

```
//Function isEmpty returns true if the queue is empty and false if it is not.
bool isEmpty(const PriorityQueue& q)
{
   if(q.cells == NULL)
   {
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

You're returning `false` if `q.cells == NULL`, when you probably meant to be returning `true` in that case, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake in isEmpty. And Yes q.cells was what the correct way to do it was.